# How can I run .exe file in Mathematica

Tags: external-calls

we have a `.exe` file. It takes input as `.txt` file and gives output as another `.txt` file.

Now, I want to run that `.exe` file from `MM`.

I tried in 2 way,

Case 1 :

using `SystemOpen[]`.

It showing the following Window, Once I run the `SystemOpen[path]`.

[image]

I click on `Run` button.after it's not showing anything.

for my conformation, Manually I double click on `.exe` file. it's working fine. but `SystemOpen[]` was not working.

case 2:

I created `.bat` file with the following code

```
   cd C:\Users\Infratab Bangalore\Desktop\Rod's
   Infratab1-2.exe
```

Now I open `.bat` file using same function `SystemOpen[]`. here it's working great.

How can I fix `case 1` problem. If anybody knows suggest me.

Thanks.

Comment: The [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExternalPrograms.html) on running external programs would be a good place to start

Comment: @SimonWoods I tried with `Run` and `Runthrough` in the following way. but not working
Run[.exe FilePath]

Comment: @SimonWoods If I use any functions like, `CompilationTarget`.it showing `A C compiler cannot be found on your system. Please consult the \
documentation to learn how to set up suitable compilers`. so Am I need to install `C` in my system.

Comment: Thanks for adding some relevant information.  That at least looks like a question that one can attempt to answer now, so I have reopened this.

Comment: I imagine this is likely a path issue.

Comment: I tried opening exe file with SystemOpen[] it was working fine.why dont u try opening some other exe file.Also try changing directory.

Comment: Have you tried unchecking the "Always ask before opening" checkbox in that dialog that came up?

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following.

```
file = OpenWrite[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "testfile.bat"}]]
WriteString[file, "call path"]
```

And then use `SystemOpen` to call the file.

Comment: Why do I need to create another files. Already I have `Input` files,just I need to execute `.exe` file.Automatically it will take every thing.

Comment: @subbu I dont know much about the internals, I was just trying to get it to work.